# PIP search - HTTPError: 503 Server Error: Backend is unhealthy for url

Tags: pip, pypi

I'm trying to install python-telegram-bot in my router (asuswrt) which has entware.

I'm getting "503 Server Error: Backend if unhealthy for URL"..

I tried on win10 but keep getting the same error.

```
$ pip search python
HTTP error 503 while getting https://pypi.org/pypi
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/search.py", line 48, in run
    pypi_hits = self.search(query, options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/search.py", line 65, in search
    hits = pypi.search({'name': query, 'summary': query}, 'or')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1243, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1602, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 789, in request
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/models.py", line 939, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
HTTPError: 503 Server Error: Backend is unhealthy for url: https://pypi.org/pypi
```

Comment: Hello everyone, well it seems the problem was server-side on **pypi.org**.

Now everything works. Please close the question.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

PyPI was down for scheduled maintenance.

In the future, you can check https://status.python.org/ when you have issues like this.

Comment: This link can be inconsistent with reality.  Right now pypi.org/pypi tells me that it is "down for maintenance or having an outage" while the status at the link claims "operational"